# Why Volley response is received as "[" and not JSON

Tags: android, android-volley, http-get

I am learning about [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) and I don't know why the response from  GET method is coming as a single char -> **[**.

**I am using this method to get the JSON response:**

```
    public void getJsonMethod() {
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    // String url = "https://www.w3schools.com/js/myTutorials.txt";
    String url = "http://www.google.com"; // with this url I am getting response

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("Response is: " + response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Response is not good" + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

When I am using [this link](http://www.google.com) I do get a response but when I try to use some link that contains nothing but JSON [like this one](https://www.w3schools.com/js/myTutorials.txt) my response it "[".

**I am calling this method from Activity like this:**

```
 GetJsonClass getJson = new GetJsonClass(this);
 getJson.getJsonMethod();
```

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong here?

---

### Answer + code

If anyone will start using Volley maybe this can help him :

as *David Lacroix* said in his answer, I called `stringRequest` and not`JsonArrayRequest`.

**Here is how it should have been:**

```
   public void getJsonMethod() {
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    String url = "your url";
    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            System.out.println("this is response good" + response);
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("this is response bad" + error);
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request

> StringRequest. Specify a URL and receive a raw string in response. See Setting Up a Request Queue for an example.
>   JsonObjectRequest and JsonArrayRequest (both subclasses of JsonRequest). Specify a URL and get a JSON object or array (respectively) in response.

You should be using a `JsonArrayRequest`

Answer (score 1):

[myTutorials.txt](https://www.w3schools.com/js/myTutorials.txt)  is being served with status code `304` (no proper suffix and MIME type either):

> **304 Not Modified**. If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD respond with this status code. **The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body**, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

In other terms, what the browser may display is not neccessarily the same what the server has sent. eg. `GSON` would accept that `JSON` only with option lenient enabled, because the array has no name.

see [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: Hey @Martin Zeitler, thank you for your dedication of time with this answer. Check the accepted answer to see what my problem was. Altho this may not work for the question your answer contains good information - you got my upvote.